# Подсчитать количество цифр в слове

Tags: perl

Я открываю папку, читаю все содержимые файлы(без **.** и **..**).
Помещаю их в **$runner** и вот таким образом считаю, если в файле 4 цифры.

```
if( ($runner =~ s/[0-9]//g)!=4 )
{
     print $runner."\n";
}
```

Но что-то пошло не так и имея такое содержимое папки :

```
U0204.online.xml
U204.online.xml
Run.runner.xml
```

Я наблюдаю такую картину(в консоли):

> U.online.xml

Я попробовал использовать оператор **tr** и *WOW*, он ничего не заменил,а  вывел верные строки.
Может кто объяснить почему политеральная замена работает, а обычная нет.

Comment: Ничего не понял.. в $runner что содержится? Имя файла? Нужно подсчитать сколько в его названии цифр?

Comment: Не готов ответить что вернет оператор **=~** в перл, но с точки зрения регулярных выражений идеологически верно искать четыре совпадения так:  

    s/^(?:\D*+\d){4}\D*+$/

Comment: в runner - имя файла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my @arr=qw(U0204.online.xml U204.online.xml Run.runner.xml);
foreach (@arr){
        print if ((split /\d/) == 4);
}
```

Comment: спасибо за совет. Но ... у меня уже есть рабочий вариант:

    if( ($runner =~ tr/[0-9]//g)!=4 )
    {
       print $runner."\n";
    }

Я просто хочу понять, почему tr работает, а s - нет.

Comment: Когда вы вызываете tr/SEARCHLIST//, то происходит обычный поиск без замены найденных вхождений на "", что бы всё таки такая замена происходила (найденные совпадения удалялись) необходимо использовать \d

Comment: все равно странное поведение оператора **tr**. Если вы зададите 2й аргумент : 

    tr/abcd/efgh/

то произойдет посимвольная замена. Тоесть если заданы оба аргумента, то поведение двух операторов схожее, если задан только 1 - соершенно разное поведение.